# Is it okay to ask for help in a hard Google human verification puzzle?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

It okay to ask for help to solve a hard Google human verification puzzle (Captcha)? Simple example:

[image]

Comment: This is a very simple example. I mean if they develop a hard one (you know, AI is smart).

Comment: I'm not sure quite how much of a 'puzzle' these really are. They're more a type of formulaic 'exercise' in (e.g.) identifying objects on a screen. Plus, these normally expire after a short amount of time and I doubt you'd get an answer from the community quick enough to make use of it. By all means ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), but it may not really be on-topic to post as a question on the main site.

Answer (score 3):

As these are currently made, they are not on-topic. There is no puzzle element. All to do is simply follow instructions and identify things meant to be easily identifiable. We have no way to know exactly how these might evolve in the future. Thus there's no point in legislating about nonexistent puzzles.